# Parsing XML file in python

Tags: python, xml, xml.etree

```
    import requests
    import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET


    def abc(area_code, office_code): 
        args = area_code + office_code
     url = (described bellow)
     r = requests.get(url=url)
     tree=ET.ElementTree()
     parsed_data=tree.parse(r.content)
      return parsed_data

   abc('503', '402')
```

where url is

```
url="http://www.networksolutions.ds.adp.com/NSPhoneToolDB/template/GetBusRouteFilterExpressions.xml?"\
               "Telnum=" +args+ "&FilterNamePrefix=ORPORTCDK&ReturnResult=detail"
```

when i run this thing i am getting

```
<Element 'GetBusRouteFilterExpressions' at 0x7f2abf526f48>
```

as output instead of entire file.

Answer (score 1):

You're giving it the response object itself.

Try giving it the content of the response like so `parsed_data=tree.parse(r.content)`.

Comment: yes it worked but now it just prints <Element 'GetBusRouteFilterExpressions' at 0x7f952bfc3f48>

Comment: And what's the problem

Answer (score 1):

When you make the request in python you're getting back a response object. You need to parse the body of that response instead. So

`tree.parse(r.content)`

Answer (score 0):

Read and try the example from

> The ElementTree XML API: [20.5.1.2. Parsing XML](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#parsing-xml)
>
> As an Element, root has a tag and a dictionary of attributes:
>
> ```
>     \>>> root.tag
>     'data'
>     \>>> root.attrib
>     {}
> ```
>
> It also has children nodes over which we can iterate:
>
> ```
>     \>>> for child in root:
>     ...     print(child.tag, child.attrib)
>     ...
>     country {'name': 'Liechtenstein'}
>     country {'name': 'Singapore'}
>     country {'name': 'Panama'}
> ```
>
> Children are nested, and we can access specific child nodes by index:
>
> ```
>    \ >>> root[0][1].text
>     '2008'
> ```